# After creating user from apex, user is not getting email for creating new password

Tags: apex

I am working on a scenario in which on creating a contact than a user from apex code.
I am not able to send a welcome email with the URL of setting new password.
here is my code:

```
    public Static void CreateContact_User(String conFirstName, String conLastName, String conEmail, String accId, String deprtmnt, String mobileNo, String city, String emailEnkey, String timeZnKey, String localSKey, String langLocalKey, String CompName ){
        Contact contactRecord       = new Contact();
        contactRecord.FirstName     = conFirstName;
        contactRecord.LastName      = conLastName;
        contactRecord.Email         = conEmail;
        contactRecord.AccountId     = accId;
        contactRecord.Department    = deprtmnt;
        contactRecord.MobilePhone   = mobileNo;
        contactRecord.MailingCity   = city;
        insert contactRecord;

        Profile portalProfile                    = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Customer Community User' Limit 1];

        Database.DMLOptions DmlO                 = new Database.DMLOptions();
        DmlO.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail        = true;

        User user1 = new User(UserName = contactRecord.Email, FirstName = contactRecord.FirstName, LastName = contactRecord.LastName, Alias = conLastName,
                              Email= contactRecord.Email, ContactId = contactRecord.ID, ProfileId = portalProfile.Id, EmailEncodingKey = emailEnkey,
                              CommunityNickname = contactRecord.FirstName, TimeZoneSidKey = timeZnKey, LocaleSidKey = localSKey,
                              LanguageLocaleKey = langLocalKey, CompanyName= CompName );
        Insert user1;     

        Database.SaveResult result = Database.update(user1 ,DmlO);
        System.debug('result:- '+result);

        User userId = [Select Id from User where Id=:user1.Id];
        System.debug('Users Id :- '+userId);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_EmailHeader.htm

[image]

Based on the above, you'd replace your insert call with a database call using the information linked and shown above.

```
Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;

database.insert(user1, dlo);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but it's not working.

Comment: I'd check if you're in a sandbox that email delivery is turned on. Otherwise, I don't think there's any options left if the documentation is incorrect or I'm misreading it.